# Array of integers sum to 0

Tags: algorithm, list, dynamic-programming, pseudocode

I am working on a problem that has me stumped. We are given a list of integers

*(v1, v2, v3, ... vn)*

that sum to a number **L**, and we are supposed to find an dynamic programming algorithm that returns another list of numbers

*(x1, x2, x3, ... xn) ∈ {0, 1}*

such that **(-1)^x1 * v1 + (-1)^x2 * v2 + ... + (-1)^xn * vn = 0**, and will know if there is no solution like that. To me it just looks like a variation of the subset sum problem but I am confused as to how to go about the memoization. It's just about designing the algorithm, pseudocode or just a hint would be fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are all v1...vn positive or can they be negative as well?

Comment: Your final formula is basically saying to either add or subtract each element of $v_n$ to the sum. If you group them by whether you are adding or subtracting then the ones that you are adding will sum to the inverse of those you are subtracting. ie if the sum of those with $x_i=0$ is A then the sum of those with $x_i=1$ will be -A. If you normalised all of them to positive numbers beforehand you could then find the sum of the whole set, divide it by 2 and then find a subset that sums to that. Whether this helps or not I don't know but it does then become a more traditional subset problem.

Comment: Have you put any effort so far?

Answer (score 1):

First step is to recognise that it doesn't matter if v<sub>k</sub> is negative or not. Since you can manipulate the signs in your output freely, you can just assume that all your inputs are non-negative.

The next step is to observe what happens to your sum when you flip the sign of v<sub>k</sub>: you add -2*v<sub>k</sub>.

So with that in mind you can rephrase the question like this:

> Given a set of non-negative numbers v<sub>1</sub>...v<sub>n</sub>,
>   that sum to `X`, can you find a subset of
>   2*v<sub>1</sub>...2*v<sub>n</sub> so that they also sum to `X`?

Which is a subset-sum problem with a target value of `X`.

But since the complement of any such subset would also add up to `X`, this is also a case of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Comment: Excellent, this is probably the fastest answer (also memory-wise). A nice reduction to [partition problem](http://marcodiiga.github.io/knapsack-problem).

Answer (score 1):

This problem turns out to be whether you can find a partition S1 = {vi1, vi2, ...vim} in the the set S = {v1, v2, ... vn}, such that sum of S1 is equal to the sum(S)/2. (note, if sum(s) % 2 == 1, it will return False) Also, we can assume them all bigger than 0

So we will use dynamic programming to do it.

dp[i, j] is true if there exits a subset in {v1, v2, .. vi} is equal j

so dp[i, j] = dp[i-1, j] or dp[i-vj, j-1]

we initialize the dp[0, j] = True for all j. and if dp[tmp, j] = false if tmp < 0.

So you can do solve the problem. However, the time complexity and space complexity is not good. Hope we have friends can provide a better solutions.

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented a functional and dynamic programming approach in JS as follows. I believe if the sum is odd there is no solution.

The following code produces an array 0f 10 items of random integers among 1-20 and then works on it by obtaining the subarray combinations dynamically.

```js
function findPowers(a,s = a.reduce((p,c) => p+c)){
  if (s & 1) return [];
  return a.reduce((p,c,i) => p.concat(p.map((n,i,m) => [n[0]-c, i+m.length, 2*(n[0]-c) === s])),[[s,0,false]])
          .filter(f => f[2])
          .map(s => Array(a.length).fill().map((b,i) => s[1] >> i & 1));
}

var arr = Array(10).fill().map(n => ~~(Math.random()*20)+1);
console.log("Input Array:",JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log("Sum:", arr.reduce((p,c) => p+c));
console.log("Powers:",JSON.stringify(findPowers(arr)));
```

Explanation:

```
if (s & 1) return [];
```

return an empty array if the sum is odd.

```
a.reduce((p,c,i) => p.concat(p.map((n,i,m) => [n[0]-c, i+m.length, 2*(n[0]-c) === s])),[[s,0,false]])
```

This is where we the dynamical magic happens. This will map our input array into it's combinations by taking the already solved previous map and applying the current element to obtain a same size array with the previous one and concatenating it over the previous one. For instance for an input array of `[1,2,3]` it will produce the following map.

```
[ [ 6, 0, false ],
  [ 5, 1, false ],
  [ 4, 2, false ],
  [ 3, 3, true ],  // where index 3 is 011 in 2^3 items array
  [ 3, 4, true ],  // where index 4 is 010 in 2^3 items array
  [ 2, 5, false ],
  [ 1, 6, false ],
  [ 0, 7, false ] ]
```

in which the first item is the sum of selected elements less total sum, the second is it's index in the map and the third is whether the `(sum of selected elements * 2)` makes the sum of input array. The third item is redundant though since it can be checked over the first item at the filtering stage. I have just included it for clarity. So we are now interested in the `true` ones so we filter them out with

```
.filter(f => f[2])
```

then all we need is the index values to be converted into binary and that's what you have asked for.

```
.map(s => Array(a.length).fill().map((b,i) => s[1] >> i & 1));
```